# Johansen Test in python

Tags: python, cointegration, statsmodels

How to get the trace statistics from the Johansen test for cointegration in python.
Also, i tried to search it myself on google, found the following website ("http://www.drtomstarke.com/index.php/johansen-test-for-cointegration"), which uses the following code "from johansen import coint_johansen".

Is there a module called johansen. If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

Just to get question answered: module is still excluded from main branch, it is contained in branch **coint** @ https://github.com/josef-pkt/statsmodels.git
But I haven't tested it myself yet.

See [Getting cointegration vectors using Johansen method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112355/getting-cointegration-vectors-using-johansen-method)